# Excel Dynamic Links

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I know this is a simple fix, but all my searching has not uncovered the answer. I need to create a dynamic hyperlink.

Sheet 1 
Column A1 = 3/0/1
Column A2 = 3/0/2

Sheet 2
Column C3 = 3/0/1
Column D3 = 3/0/2

Now, creating a link on Sheet 2 to the appropriate cell in Sheet 1 is easy.  Think is, Sheet 1 has the potential to be sorted in a variety of ways.  So I need the link dynamic.  I need it to find "3/0/1" whether it's in column A1 or A77, or whatever.

I've seen examples using the ADDRESS function within the HYPERLINK function, but can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might actually be one of those time when you *want* to use `.Selection` to govern which cells the macro is enacted upon.

```
Sub hlink_Sel()
    Dim fnd As Range, sel As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each sel In Selection
            Set fnd = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:=sel.Text, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print fnd.Address(0, 0, xlA1, external:=True)
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sel, Address:="", _
                   SubAddress:=fnd.Address(0, 0, xlA1, external:=True), TextToDisplay:=sel.Text
            End If
        Next sel
    End With
    Set fnd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Just select some cells that are supposed to have their values duplicated in Sheet1's column A and run the macro. Given the odd nature of your sample data, I've used `.Text` as the search term in the find operation. Note that the `.Address` function has the *external* parameter set to true in order that the worksheet name is included.